# How to detect the anomaly in a time series data with trend and seasonality present?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, seasonality, anomaly-detection

I want to detect the outliers in a time series data which contains the trend and seasonality components. I want to leave out the peaks which are seasonal and only consider only the other peaks. As I am new to time series analysis, Please assist me to approach this problem.

The coding platform am using is Python.

Comment: The above link is relevant for R language. I am seeking assistance in python packages and models.

Comment: Raja, welcome to CV! Questions about implementation are off-topic here. You could try asking about this on StackOverflow, which is a programming Q&A. However, they too will not write an entire implementation for you. You may want to make your question more specific first, perhaps by reading about time series more first. You can also search for questions that are about time series here, or on StackOverflow.